Working with the norm map of ideles
Firstly, let me define the relevant notation. Let $L/K$ be an abelian extension of number fields. We let $\mathbb{I}_K$ be the ideles of $K$, $C_K = \mathbb{I}_K / K^\times$ the idele class group, $\mathbb{I}_K(\mathfrak{m}) = \{ \alpha \in \mathbb{I}_K \mid \alpha \equiv 1 \pmod{\mathfrak{m}} \}$, $C_K(\mathfrak{m}) = \mathbb{I}_K(\mathfrak{m})K^\times / K^\times$, $\mathbb{I}^{\langle \mathfrak{m} \rangle} = \{ \alpha \in \mathbb{I}_K \mid \alpha_\mathfrak{p} = 1 \text{ for all } \mathfrak{p} \mid \mathfrak{m} \}$, and $N_{L/K}$ the norm map on ideles given by
$$N_{L/K}(\alpha)_\mathfrak{p} = \prod_{\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}} N_{L_\mathfrak{P} / K_\mathfrak{p}}(\alpha_\mathfrak{P}).$$
With this notation, my lecturer writes the following:
$$N_{L/K}(C_L)/C_K(\mathfrak{m}) = N_{L/K}\mathbb{I}_L K^\times / \mathbb{I}_K(\mathfrak{m}) K^\times = N_{L/K}\mathbb{I}_L^{\langle \mathfrak{m} \rangle}\mathbb{I}_K(\mathfrak{m}) K^\times / \mathbb{I}_K(\mathfrak{m})K^\times$$
I'm honestly completely lost at these two equalities. Firstly, I find it extremely unclear what $N_{L/K}$ is acting on, as no brackets are written. I presume this is somewhat standard and that it must be clear to most people what the brackets should be around. How should I know in general what the norm group is acting on?
Secondly, I don't really understand the equalities under any possibility for the brackets. I was thinking something like $N_{L/K}(C_L) = N_{L/K}(\mathbb{I}_L)K^\times / K^\times$ and then using the second isomorphism theorem, however, even the equality $N_{L/K}(C_L) = N_{L/K}(\mathbb{I}_L)K^\times / K^\times$ isn't clear to me (if it is true). The final equality just doesn't make any sense to me either, especially as there are three possibilities for where the brackets should go. I know that $\mathbb{I}_L = \mathbb{I}_L^{\langle \mathfrak{m} \rangle} \mathbb{I}_K(\mathfrak{m}) L^\times$, but I can't see the solution.
I guess both of these equalities relate to what $N_{L/K}(L^\times)$ is. I can see it if $N_{L/K}(L^\times) = K^\times$, but I thought that $$N_{L/K}(L^\times) = \{u \pi^{fn} \in K^\times \mid u \in \mathcal{O}_K^\times, n \in \mathbb{Z}\},$$ so we only have this equality if the residue field degree is $1$ (I mean the whole point of the existence theorem is that we can get all finite-index closed subgroups, it's not always $K^\times$ right?) However, maybe it's supposed to be obvious in any case.
Any help would be much appreciated!!
